# npm start starts the process to a different user

Tags: node.js, npm

I ran the following command as the root user.

`npm start`

But npm start switched the user to ubuntu before running the program.

Any ideas what could cause this? This happened only after I upgraded to:

```
Here are the logs

root$ npm start --verbose 

npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/node-v16.13.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'start',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.1.0
npm info using node@v16.13.0
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/local/node-v16.13.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 6ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 6ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/site/exmonitor/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/local/node-v16.13.0-linux-x64/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 16ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 16ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 45ms

> app@0.0.0 start
> node ./bin/www

Port 80 requires elevated privilegesload Completed in 45ms
```

Comment: sudo npm run start

Comment: @Nick   Didn't work, I tried sudo and I'm already running it as root.  I clarified the question. thx

Comment: Did you called `process.setuid` in your program?

Comment: You need to post some code

Comment: I do not do process.setuid

Answer (score 1):

Changing the owner of the folder you're running npm in (cwd) should fix it.
If you're running as root:

```
chown -R root:root ./
```

There may be other repercussions when changing file ownership, though.

The issue is in an old version of `@npmcli/promise-spawn`, which specifically avoids running scripts as root:

```
 const isRoot = process.getuid && process.getuid() === 0
 const { uid, gid } = isRoot ? inferOwner.sync(cwd) : {}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70868645/4646226 and https://github.com/npm/promise-spawn/commit/a8b21fc66b31e3d724f6b91c77d8bc4f6172ed13#diff-e727e4bdf3657fd1d798edcd6b099d6e092f8573cba266154583a746bba0f346

Note: I know this is an old question, but it came up on Google for me, and I finally fixed it, so decided to contribute :).