# Why does running "npm run <script>" as root switch user?

Tags: npm, root, npm-scripts

I setup a new project inside an alpine image (`node:16-alpine`), in `/app2`, with the following structure:

```
- node_modules
  - .bin
    - dummy
- package.json
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dummy": "dummy",
  },
  ...
}
```

dummy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

setInterval(() => console.log("."), 1000)
```

Now when i run `npm run dummy` with root user, instead of the root user, the node command will run with whatever user owns the project root directory. Eg:

```
/app2 # ls -lah
...    
drwxr-xr-x    3 node2    node        4.0K Jan 17 08:27 .
...

/app2 # whoami
root

/app2 # npm run dummy
...

# in a different terminal:
/app2 # ps x
...
  816 root      0:00 npm run dummy
  827 node2     0:00 node /app2/node_modules/.bin/dummy
...
```

This does not happen if I'm not running npm with root (eg: `su node && npm run dummy` will run as `node` user, and not `node2`).

Why is this? Does any know if this is documented anywhere? Or how can I run the scripts as root? (i know it's not recommended, but it's inside a docker container and for development only)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This happens in `@npmcli/promise-spawn`

```
 const isRoot = process.getuid && process.getuid() === 0
 const { uid, gid } = isRoot ? inferOwner.sync(cwd) : {}
```

You cannot find documentation as this behavior was [removed a while ago](https://github.com/npm/promise-spawn/commit/a8b21fc66b31e3d724f6b91c77d8bc4f6172ed13#diff-e727e4bdf3657fd1d798edcd6b099d6e092f8573cba266154583a746bba0f346).

This is an old note removed in that commit that described the behavior you see:

> Note: When the current user is root, this will use
> [`infer-owner`](http://npm.im/infer-owner) to find the owner of the current
> working directory, and run with that effective uid/gid.  Otherwise, it runs
> as the current user always.  (This helps prevent doing git checkouts and
> such, and leaving root-owned files lying around in user-owned locations.)

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems npm cli is till using an old version of this package (as of now, npm cli 8.4.0 uses promise-spawn 1.3.2), which includes this magic

Comment: Latest version of cordova (cordova-lib/cordova-fetch) uses promise-spawn 1.3.2 too. I found this error when I was using a plugin hosted by github and the project folder had a different owner than the current one. So, when I ran `cordova prepare`, it tried to pull the plugin, but printed out `CordovaError: Error: An unknown git error occurred` (so bad error description, I spent 4 hours to find the reason)